# Is it possible to for two computers to communicate over the internet without using central server in real time

Tags: networking, network-programming

Is it possible to for two computers to communicate over the internet without using  central server in real time?
if yes
how do the communicating computers know each others ip address,

as far as i know most computers connected to the Internet through the ISP's are allocated dynamic ip address.So how does the computer intiating the transmission know the receiving computers ip address.

My goal is to build a software that would transfer a few bytes of data from Computer A to Computer B without going through a central server.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to for two computers to communicate over the internet

Yes, provided any intervening firewalls permit.

> without using central server

Yes.

> in real time?

Not unless you have a real-time network and real-time operating systems at both ends: or else you are abusing the computer-science 'real-time', in which case don't.

> if yes how do the communicating computers know each others ip address

Via configuration, DNS, user input, ... Too broad.