# How do I use a server hosting a web application to set two users up to communicate with each other without a server?

Tags: networking, network-programming

I want two users of my web application to agree to communicate with each other, and then my server would no longer be relied on for the communication. What are my options to have two computers communicate over the internet without relying on my server? How would I set this up--specifically, what API or protocol could I use?

I want to allow the users to run various secure computations, and I don't want my server to act as a trusted third party.

[This previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27762844/is-it-possible-to-for-two-computers-to-communicate-over-the-internet-without-usi) discusses the problem, but the answer is very vague. I know very little about doing web anything, and I'm having trouble finding where to look. Someone pointed me to the xmlhttprequest API, but I don't see how that is helpful.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible with pretty new [WebRTC](https://webrtc.org/architecture/) technology. You should look at
data channels between clients. RTCDataChannel API provides secure (DTLS based) peer-to-peer communication. Not all browsers have support of the WebRTC and among them not all supports RTCDataChannel API. So beware browser compatibility problems.